# unable to store a string with commas in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the following line to store a string in database but am currently unable to store it as a single string. Every time it encounters a comma in the string it creates a new row in the database table.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageURL", String.Join(",", img.ToArray()));
```

What is the way to go about it?

this is how i have defined the table:

```
@ImageURL VARCHAR(max)

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;


  Insert statements for procedure here
  insert into 
  DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(100) 

  SET @String =''            

  IF(LEN(@Images)>0)        
  BEGIN        
       DELETE FROM Business_images WHERE BusinessId=@BusinessId        
  END        

  WHILE LEN(@ImageURL) > 0              
  BEGIN           
    SET @String = LEFT(@ImageURL, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @ImageURL) - 1, -1),  LEN(@ImageURL)))              
    SET @ImageURL = SUBSTRING(@ImageURL, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @ImageURL), 0), LEN(@ImageURL)) + 1, LEN(@ImageURL)) 

    insert into Images(ImageURL) values (@String)
  END
END
```

Comment: What is the type of `img`? What is the source code for the query or stored procedure you are calling?

Comment: _"creates a new row"_ O_o   What is your command query?

Comment: If you use .NET 4.0, you can use `String.Join(",", img)` (if `img` is of type `IEnumerable<String>`)

Comment: I am getting a string till here. Which is like xyz,abc,pqr but when it stores in the databse it stores like:
xyz
abc
pqr
that is in 3 different rows

I am editing and will post the table defination in a minute. thanks

Comment: Apparently the stored procedure above splits a string into single rows at comma positions and therefore reverses your C# `String.Join`.

Comment: It looks like your insert procedure is splitting the string and performing an insert for each element.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the answers!! It solved my problem. As you guys pointed out, it was indeed the SP that was splitting the string. I removed the "While" loop from the code and it worked!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string specialString = "this is silly, string,,not so special''special";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into t1 (col1) VALUES (@parame)"))
    {
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parame",specialString);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

FYI: I was able to insert into sql server. In my case `col1` is of type `nvarchar`

Comment: @MayankPahuja: No, it's not exactly what you have done, s_nair is using a `SqlCommand` with [`CommandType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx) `Text` whereas you've (most likely) used `StoredProcedure`.

Comment: Is there an insert trigger defined on the table that splits the text at comma positions?